# Recursive function returns NA

Tags: r, function, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function to calculate the following

Where T is the number of rows in the dataset, and α, l<sub>0</sub> are predefined.

[image]

For this, I tried to write a recursive function, but it returns NA

```
calc_sum <- function(y, a, l){
    return(a*(y[nrow(y),])+ (1-a)*calc_sum(y[1:(nrow(y)-1),], a, l))
  }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing or where I'm going wrong.

Data

```
y <- data.frame(Count=c(94200, 105700, 96500, 117100, 104600, 100500, 94700, 93900, 93200, 78000))
```

The expected output at a = 0.572 and l = 98527.78 is 84976.37

Comment: It might be helpful to know if `y` contains any `NA`s.  In fact, seeing all of your datset would be helpful.  As well as your expected output.  I'm also not sure why your function needs to be recursive.

Comment: @Limey updated the question with data and expected output. I am not sure what the most efficient way of implementing the function is, hence used a recursive function

Comment: I’m surprised your function returns *at all*, since the recursion is currently missing a base case — it should keep calling itself infinitely (until R interrupts it).

Comment: Furthermore, I *love* recursion. Really do. I use it wherever it makes sense. But I don’t feel that it makes a lot of sense here. Your equation can be written pretty directly in R: `sum(a * (1 - a) ^ (0 : (T - 1)) * y[seq(T, 1)]) + (1 - a) ^ T * l`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion doesn’t offer a very natural solution here. In fact, the equation translates into R as a one-liner:

```
sum(a * (1 - a) ^ (0 : (T - 1)) * y[seq(T, 1)]) + (1 - a) ^ T * l
```

Put into a function:

```
mysum = function (y, a, l) {
    T = length(y)
    sum(a * (1 - a) ^ (0 : (T - 1)) * y[seq(T, 1)]) + (1 - a) ^ T * l
}
```

Called with a vector (not a data.frame!).